# Why do websites ask me to enter email address and password again

Tags: user-interface, validation

I was just looking for a todolist service over the net. I encountered this tadalist site http://tadalist.com/. Now I was making an account for myself. On this page it asked me to enter email address again and password again. Many sites where I have created an account this thing is done of asking the user to re-enter details.

I don't get the purpose of specifically asking the user to enter email address or the password or any other field.

I can always copy paste and get through this field's duplicate. Why do they have such a thing. As I see it we need to do client side validation for correct entries which is really unnecessary operations as I see it. Why is it done? Pretty sure there's good enough reason for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its to make sure that you don't have typo in your password or email address.

imagine that you had a typo on your password, you won't be able to login to the site anymore, unless you reset your password.

its same for email. if you make a typo in your email address, potentially your details can be sent to another email address.

its not good idea to copy and paste in this kind of situation. its better to type them again to make sure they are entered correctly.

Comment: But what's the point if sites let me have a copy paste enabled.Moreover in passwords we cannot see, so no one can point out where I've made a mistake and what if I'm using one of my frequently used passwords and make that mistake twice.Still I cannot login.Apart from typo's I really can't think if there is any other reason to do this

Comment: @gizgok: for password, at least it will tell you that passwords are not matched and you need to renter them again. its good enough to prevent you to enter a wrong password. it is not very common to make same mistake twice, but in case you do no one can help you :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the idea behind making you repeat emails is to reduce input errors. When you input your email, you might make a typing error. Forcing you to slow down and look again at what you typed will presumably lower typos, even if you don't retype and just copy and paste. For passwords, you can't see what you type, so retyping will definitely help there.

Comment: Same comment as mentioned to mohammed.But what's the point if sites let me have a copy paste enabled.Moreover in passwords we cannot see, so no one can point out where I've made a mistake and what if I'm using one of my frequently used passwords and make that mistake twice.Still I cannot login.Apart from typo's I really can't think if there is any other reason to do this

Comment: The point is just to slow you down. And not just in case you mistype. Many browsers have auto-fill for emails and the like, making you pay attention to what is in the box is a good thing. It's easy to skip over a filled-in email box that is incorrect (perhaps it has your personal email and you want your work email), but if there is a second box you need to copy into presumably you will be fully aware of what the form is asking for and why.